Integrating Firebase Analytics into Playable Ads - Cocos Creator Typescript
I'm trying to use Firebase Analytics in a Playable Ads project with Cocos Creator Typescript 3.8. I looked around but couldn't find how to do it exactly. Has anyone done this before?
I need help with:
Can Firebase Analytics work with Playable Ads in Cocos Creator?
Any simple steps to get Firebase Analytics into a Cocos Creator 3.8 project?
Thanks for any tips or links!
